# RxJava2: Perform operation on data which was successfully send to REST api

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have this specific issue for which I cannot find a clean solution.

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap { constructData() }
    .subscribe { data ->
        api.syncData(data)
            .repeat()
            .subscribe { response ->
                deleteSyncedData(data)
            }
    }
```

So as you can see from the code I need to construct some data package to send it to the backend and after it is correctly sent I'm deleting it from my local storage system. Right now it's working but looks a little bit like callback hell - what if I wanted to combine response with data and then make a request?

Does anyone see a better solution for this kind of operation?

Additionally I'd like to know how to switch between schedulers between those operations? I want to execute `constructData()` and `deleteSyncedData()` on `Schedulers.computation()` but `api.syncData(data)` on `Schedulers.io()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Rx doc for SubscribeOn](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html):

You cannot use `subscribeOn()` multiple times in your `chain`. Technically, you can do so, but that won’t have any additional effect. In your code, if you are chaining two different `Schedulers` using `subscribeOn()` only the one closed to the source `observable` will take its effect and nothing else.

But you can achieve the same using `observeOn()`. You can switch between multiple `Schedulers` using `observeOn()` and then finally `observe` the result on `MainThread`

**Example:**

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .flatMap { constructData() }
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap { data -> api.syncData(data).map { data } }
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .flatMap { data -> deleteSyncedData(data) }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { data ->

    }
```

But in my opinion this is also fine.

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap { constructData() }
    .subscribe { data ->
        api.syncData(data)
            .repeat()
            .subscribe { response ->
                deleteSyncedData(data)
            }
    }
```

Comment: api.syncData(data) doesn't return data.

Comment: Also you missed the whole point. The Schedulers question was additional to the more important question of how to pass the received value down the chain.

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk I have edit the answer. Hope that helps.